# Rpi 2 wont start after 3.3v and 0v short

Tags: gpio, boot

I was working on a project when I shorted pin 3.3v and 0v. I thought it would restart like normal, but instead of restarting, it wouldn't boot. Both the red and green leds are solid. I have tried multiple sd cards.

Comment: :( Sorry to hear that. I think I did something similar once which killed my pi. Is anything getting hot when you turn it on?

Comment: Give it a few days and try it again if it still does nothing, then it's time for a new Pi. At least their cheap.

Answer (score 2):

Accept you need a new pi.

Try putting you SD card in another pi and booting that.  When it works, put it back into your old pi.

Try booting the old pi, and with a multimeter check the difference between 0 and 3.3v pins.  Odds on bet it's no longer 3.3v.

Buy a new pi 3.  Rejoice that you have a valid excuse to upgrade.   (Yes, the author of this answer wants one but can't, because he can't justify it to himself.  Pity him.)

Edit to add:  you probably took out the voltage regulator.  They aren't hugely robust.